# Apostrophe in fstab

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

Can's get a window's directory to mount due to an apostrophe. The relevant bit of fstab:

```
# Auto-mount windows drive
UUID=0C1C51021C50E86A /media/windows ntfs defaults 0 0

# Auto-mount the Music folder
/media/windows/Documents\040and\040Settings/Foo\040Name/My\040Documents/My\040Music/Foo's\040Music /home/foo/Music none bind 0 0
```

Note that I'm using the \040 to escape spaces, but `man ascii` doesn't (from what I see) have an escape character for a '. I've tried \047 to no avail

Thoughts?

Comment: can you post the output or errors you get when you try mounting that manually as root?   sudo mount /home/foo/Music

Comment: user flagged that they no longer have this computer - closing this for now.

Answer (score 2):

I've used 047 for apostrophe. It worked.

```
/home/anwar/Anwar\047s\040Pictures /mnt none bind 0 0
```

I think, you should check the syntax. The folder in my home is "Anwar's Pictures". It is mounted in `/mnt`.

Check [this page](http://www.csgnetwork.com/asciiset.html).

Your line should be

```
/media/windows/Documents\040and\040Settings/Foo\040Name/My\040Documents/My\040Music/Foo\047s\040Music /home/foo/Music none bind 0
```

Comment: Hm. This works properly when doing `mount -a`, but at boot it does not work. I did modify your command to make the end 0 0 instead of just one 0

Comment: Any chance you have the exact line you used? I'm wondering if the `late` option would help here, but I can't find any documentation on it

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing this in your fstab file, you can use a symbolic link that will work whenever the windows partition is mounted.  You can create that with the following command:

```
ln -s "/media/windows/Documents and Settings/Foo Name/My Documents/My Music/Foo's Music" /home/foo/Music
```

Note the double quotes will make the spaces work properly - much simpler than the mount method.

[updated question since using 'bind' as an option with a folder is valid, thanks neon_overload]

Comment: He's using a mount of type `bind` which *is* designed to mount a folder rather than a partition.

Nonetheless your suggestion for a symbolic link may still be a useful alternative.

Comment: It may be - I'm under the impression that the symbolic link may have issues with the partition being mounted at boot (I've used symbolic links extensively on one partition, but not as much across partitions). If this isn't the case, would it be better in any way to use one approach over the other?

Comment: symbolic links (specified by the "-s" option) can cross partitions, though regular "hard" links would have problems with that.